# Solve system of linear equations in Python

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have a system of symbolic linear equations

```
i1 = id2 - u1/zg
i2 = (C+D*Y)*u1 + D* i1
i2 = u2/zl
u2 = (A+B*Y)*u1 + B*i1
```

My goal is the solution for u2, where u1 and i1 are substituted with their corresponding solutions declared above. The solution for u2 is this huge equation, calculated by hand for now

```
u2 = (A+B*Y)*(id1*zg*(-B + D*zl)/(A*zg + B*Y*zg - B - C*zg*zl - D*Y*zg*zl + D*zl)) + B * (id1 - (id1*zg*(-B + D*zl)/(A*zg + B*Y*zg - B - C*zg*zl - D*Y*zg*zl + D*zl))/zg)
```

Im sure theres a way to let Python calculate this for me, because it takes ages and is very error prone doing this manually.

Basically I want that Python eliminates all unknown variables (except one, which I then can calculate) for me. In the example set of equations above, i1 i2 u1 and u2 are unknown. Everything else is known.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `sympy`: `symbols` , `Eq` and a solver

Comment: Thanks, yeah i should have said that, i already tried this, i declared the equations above via Eq(...) and then tried to solve them via

sym.linsolve(equations, (u2, u1, i1))

But then Python just outputs the already declared u2, so I must have done something wrong.

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question with that (`equations`) **and** all the symbols...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
# unkowns
i1, i2, u1, u2 = symbols("i1, i2, u1, u2")
# knows quantities
id2, zg, zl, A, B, C, D, Y = symbols("id_2, z_g, z_l, A, B, C, D, Y")

# define equations:
# one way to do that is to write them as:
# (Left Hand Side) - (Right Hand Side) = 0
eq1 = i1 - (id2 - u1/zg)
eq2 = i2 - ((C+D*Y)*u1 + D* i1)
eq3 = i2 - (u2/zl)
eq4 = u2 - ((A+B*Y)*u1 + B*i1)

# solve the system of equation
sol = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4], [i1, i2, u1, u2])
# retrieve the solution of u2
sol[u2]
# out: (A*D*id_2*z_g*z_l - B*C*id_2*z_g*z_l)/(A*z_g + B*Y*z_g - B - C*z_g*z_l - D*Y*z_g*z_l + D*z_l)
```

Comment: I also noticed that my own solution i found earlier (answer below) is still wrong, yours is correct, the result is exactly what i expected. You really made my day, the world needs more humans like you.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I solved it as follows:

```
equations = [
    sym.Eq( (C+D*Y)*u1 + D* i1 , i2 ),
    sym.Eq( id2 - u1/zg, i1),
    sym.Eq(u2/zl, i2),
    sym.Eq( (A+B*Y)*u1 + B*i1, u2 )
]

eq = sym.solve(equations, u2)
```

I tried exactly that before, but must had a typo somewhere.

The result is

```
id1*zg*(-B + D*zl)/(A*zg + B*Y*zg - B - C*zg*zl - D*Y*zg*zl + D*zl)
```

Its way shorter than the result i calculated per hand, but it seems to be correct.